# Is it necessary for all slaves and the master need to have the same user name in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

1. Should all the slaves and master should have the same user name?
2. Should all the slaves and master should have the hadoop in the same path?

if yes, Is there any way to overcome the above restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the (namenode, datanode) share the same user and that the (jobtracker,tasktracker) share a same user (not necessarily the same user as the (namenode,datanode). So to answer your question (1): yes.

For #2, you should have all master/slave machines share same hadoop version and preferably in same directory structure. You can use a deployment tool such as puppet/chef/ansible/etc or simply rsync to maintain the files identically on all the systems